# how to install specific version of MFP Eclipse Studio

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I would like to install MFP Eclipse Studio version [interim fix: 7.1.0.0-MFPF-IF201511141616](http://www-933.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/swg/downloadFixes?parent=ibm~Other%2Bsoftware&product=ibm/Other+software/IBM+MobileFirst+Platform+Foundation&release=7.1.0.0&platform=Windows&function=fixId&fixids=7.1.0.0-MFPF-IF201511141616&includeRequisites=0&includeSupersedes=0&downloadMethod=http).

I have downloaded this file(7.1.0.0-MFPF-StudioP2-IF201511141616.zip) from the given link. Can any one help me to know the steps required to install this.

Answer (score 3):

First, you need to install the supported Eclipse IDE
http://www-969.ibm.com/software/reports/compatibility/clarity-reports/report/html/prereqsForProduct?deliverableId=46183B706BEA11E48038141DE954FC88

Then you install the MFP Studio ifix as normal plugin installation via Help > Install new software.  Detail steps for the MFP Studio installation can be found here:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/devenv/t_installing_ibm_worklight_studi.html